# Имя "Base" отсутствует в текущем контексте

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms, sql

Здравствуйте. Я пишу веб форму Asp.net на C# в среде VS2010.

Моя задача по нажатию кнопки записать в базу данные. К базе я подключен, сама база работает, но при попытке выполнения выходит ошибка :

> Имя "Base" отсутствует в текущем контексте

В строке

```
SqlConnection mconn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString : Base);
```

Код :

```
SqlConnection mconn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString : Base);  
mconn.Open();   
SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand(" INSERT ...  ", mconn);  
mconn.Close();

...

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Data" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Base %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table]">
             </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Web config

```
<connectionStrings>  
<add name="Base" connectionString="Data Source=10.120.60.190;Initial     Catalog=Table;User ID=user;Password=password"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Подскажите, как можно исправить ошибку? Спасибо.

Comment: @Andy92, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Ну, а что вы хотели? Что, по-вашему, означает `ConnectionString` и `Base` в `new SqlConnection(ConnectionString : Base)`?

(Непосредственное решение вашего вопроса [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15540806/276994), но сначала убедитесь, что вы понимаете, в чём проблема с вашим кодом.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)!

Решение было:

```
 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Base"].ToString());
```